# Mask Sensitive Data in springboot based on variable name from object and not String regex

Tags: java, spring, logback

I was looking into masking/removing sensitive information from logs but I was having some trouble using masking pattern as shown here
https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/logback-pattern-gdpr/

The problem for me is I want to mask userName that ends up being shown in toString() of class defintion.

```
String example ="com.test.sensitive.info.UserInfo@124a13241[id=12345, name=TEST, FIRST, email=123@email]
```

I tried using regex to mask this but the problem is it can get really messy if the user has special characters in name. I was wondering if there was some way to do masking based on variable name for instance of java class. Like mask value for variable name (regardless of what the value is inside).

Comment: change the toString method

Comment: it is autogenerated xml code to java . So cant touch the toString atleast not easily

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to override UserInfo's toString method and hide userName

For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "UserInfo[id = " + id + "]";
}
```

Also you don't have to print to log (all) UserInfo object

Comment: toString is from autogenerated code based on xml to java conversion so not really an option.

Comment: @Praveen ok,  you don't have to print to log (all) UserInfo object

Comment: that is the intial goal but we already have a ton of these all over the place. I am looking to create a lib of sorts that is fallback in case of such things are logged already.That can essentially act as last line of defence

Comment: to give some context I am writing a lib that can be added to fix already existing leaks quickly.So code edits is out of question based on how many places will need it